# Clickable Or Tool Tip in Plots

Tags: label, gnuplot

I have a couple of 2D plots which I am plotting using Gnuplot.

In Gnuplot, is it possible to associate clickable labels to data points? Or tool tip which will be displayed on mouse over? I am aware of permanent labels ("with labels") for data points. But I need to able to hide these labels.

If not Gnuplot, is there some other tool that has this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to set a "tool tip" with gnuplot. Therefore gnuplot has to be compiled with using mouse events. (Per default this is the case, you'd have to explicitly set a flag to not include mouse events).

The other issue you have to take into account, is that only certain terminals are capable of handling mouse events (pm, x11, ggi, windows and wxt).

Third and hopefully last only certain views can handle mouse events (2d graphs and maps).

> (i.e. splots with set view having z-rotation 0, 90, 180, 270 or 360 degrees, including set view map)

If all this is the case, mouse events can be set and configured like *set mouse* linke described [HERE](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.0/gnuplot.html#mouse).

The script below should place labels at positions where you press the middle mouse button:

```
plot sin(x)
pause -1
```

If you want to hide labels or see the coordinates of the current mouse position, simply press 'h' while the gnuplot window has the keyboard focus and a list of commands will be displayed, showing you all options currently available through keyboard and mouse bindings. But even those are configurable with the *bind* command which is described [HERE](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.0/gnuplot.html#bind).

Comment: Is it possible to save such graphs (which have tool tip)? Also, is this possible with multiplots?

Comment: Try binding some export feature to the mouse click, so that you write your labels to a separate file. Then load that file into gnuplot and replot your last plot. Sorry, but I do not know any other way.